# In a vim syntax file, how can I have "syn match" act case-insensitively?

Tags: vim

I'm starting to edit [Spider procedure files](http://www.wadsworth.org/spider_doc/spider/docs/user_doc.html#procedures) (i.e. the electron microscopy image processing program). I started creating [my own syntax and ftplugin files](https://github.com/molecules/vim-spider) for it, but wondered how I can make `syn match` act case-insensitively?

Currently I use two statements to achieve this affect (in `.vim/syntax/spider.vim`):

```
syn match spiderCommand /\<AC\>/$
syn match spiderCommand /\<ac\>/$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the following in the docs:

```
syntax case ignore
```

Maybe that helps. However, I think it applies to all the matching.

Also, since `/\<AC\>/$` is just a vim pattern, you should be able to use the standard "ignore case" directives `\c`. The following should work:

```
/\c\<AC\>/$
```

Comment: Could you possibly set this differently per filetype?